# Clearing from queue packages without downloading/installing them

Tags: 12.04, apt, package-management, dpkg

I made the mistake of trying to install the wrong version of a program using a downloaded .deb file.  It hung up partways because of unresolvable dependencies, and I had to close the shell window to abort the process.  Unfortunately, this left things in a sort of weird state where that bad version is still stuck in the list of packages to be downloaded and installed.  I've tried variations on `sudo apt-get autoclean` and `sudo apt-get clean` and `sudo apt-get autoremove`, etc. all to no avail.  I've tried running `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, but all that does is start the download/install process for the bad version again - which hangs again, and I have to go thru and clean out (via `sudo rm` various lock files and partial download folders - again.

How do I clean things up so that dkpg forgets what is in the queue completely?